# Synchronise HTML Videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Problem:
I am building 3 a column layout, where some columns must stay sticky to the top of the viewport. There is a section where I want to place the same video as background for all 3 columns and I want to achieve following effect: Leave middle column 'sticky-top' and allow the left and right column to scroll up.

I already tried a solution with <Canvas>, but there are a couple of problems. Canvases can not render frames without a blurry effect and it doesn't look good in webkit browsers (for firefox it seems to work better). **[Here is](https://codepen.io/Jeko_92/pen/zYyBGwN)** *(in case jsFiddle doesn't play video correctly, probably you need to insert Bootstrap's CDN links) a sample solution I am aiming for. I have tried to insert videos in the left and right column and adjust margins so that all three videos give feeling if they were one whole, but there I have another problem. On first run all videos play almost synchronously, but after while they flow out from sync, which looses effect of wholeness. **[Here is](https://codepen.io/Jeko_92/pen/XWoKVGJ)**  Solution with 3 background videos.

````
 ```
<div class="row g-0">
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c container-left">
            <canvas id="canvas-left" class="o-cont-m"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c container-middle sticky-top">
             <video id="video-bg-middle" loop muted autoplay playsinline>
        <!--             <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
               <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <!--               <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
        <!--                <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
        <!--                <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/Sintel.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
        <!--                       <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/SubaruOutbackOnStreetAndDirt.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.s
                </video>
          </div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-4-c container-right">
            <canvas id="canvas-right" class="o-cont-m"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c" style="background-color:grey"></div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c col-transparent sticky-top"></div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-4-c" style="background-color:grey"></div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c" style="background-color:tomato"></div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c col-transparent sticky-top" ></div>
          <div class="o-cont-m o-col-4-c" style="background-color:tomato

"></div>
</div>
````

````
    ```
  

     .o-col-3-c {
      flex:0 0 auto;
      width:30%;
     }
    
    .o-col-4-c {
      flex:0 0 auto;
      width:40%;
    }
    
    .o-cont-m {
      block-size:100vh;
    }
    
    .col-transparent{
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }
    video{
      width:100vw;
      height:100%;
      display:block;
      
      object-fit:fill;
    }
    
    .container-left,
    .container-middle,
    .container-right {
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    #canvas-left,
    #canvas-right {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    }
````

````
```
const middleCol = document.querySelector('.container-middle');
const middleColOffsetLeft = middleCol.offsetLeft;
console.log(middleColOffsetLeft);
const rightCol = document.querySelector('.container-right');
const rightColOffsetLeft = rightCol.offsetLeft;
console.log(rightColOffsetLeft);

const bgVideo = document.getElementById('video-bg-middle');
bgVideo.style.marginLeft = `-${middleColOffsetLeft}px`

const canvasLeft = document.getElementById("canvas-left");
const canvasRight = document.getElementById("canvas-right");
canvasRight.style.marginLeft = `-${rightColOffsetLeft}px`;
const ctx = canvasLeft.getContext("2d");
const ctx1 = canvasRight.getContext("2d");

function drawFrames() {
    if (!bgVideo.paused && !bgVideo.ended) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgVideo, 0, 0, canvasLeft.width, canvasLeft.height);
        ctx1.drawImage(bgVideo, 0, 0, canvasRight.width, canvasRight.height);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drawFrames); // Call drawFrames again on the next animation frame
}

bgVideo.addEventListener('play', () => {
  drawFrames();
});
````

````
    ```
     <!--THIS IS HTML FOR SOLUTION WITH VIDEOS-->
    <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c container-left overfllow-hidden">
        <video id="video-bg-left" loop muted autoplay playsinline>
           <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.s
            </video>
      </div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c container-middle sticky-top overfllow-hidden">
         <video id="video-bg-middle" loop muted autoplay playsinline>
           <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.s
            </video>
      </div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-4-c container-right overfllow-hidden">
        <video id="video-bg-right" loop muted autoplay playsinline>
           <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.s
            </video>
      </div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c" style="background-color:grey"></div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c col-transparent sticky-top"></div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-4-c" style="background-color:grey"></div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c" style="background-color:tomato"></div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-3-c col-transparent sticky-top" ></div>
      <div class="o-cont-m o-col-4-c" style="background-color:tomato"></div>
    </div>
````

`````
````
/*CSS STAYS SAME*/
.o-col-3-c {
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width:30%;
}

.o-col-4-c {
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width:40%;
}

.o-cont-m {
  block-size:100vh;
}

.col-transparent{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
video{
  width:100vw;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  
  object-fit:fill;
}

.container-left,
.container-middle,
.container-right {
overflow:hidden;
}



#video-bg-left,
#video-bg-middle {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: block;
}
`````

````
    ```
    /*JS FOR SOLUTION WITH  3 DIFFERENT VIDEOS*/
    const updateLeftMargin = () => {
        const middleCol = document.querySelector('.container-middle');
        const rightCol = document.querySelector('.container-right');
        const middleColOffsetLeft = middleCol.offsetLeft;
        const rightColOffsetLeft = rightCol.offsetLeft;
    
        const updateBackground = (elementId, marginLeft, width) => {
            const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            if (element) {
                if (marginLeft !== null) {
                    element.style.marginLeft = marginLeft < 0 ? `${marginLeft}px` : `-${marginLeft}px`;
                }
                if (width !== null) {
                    element.style.width = `${width}px`;
                }
            }
        };
    
        updateBackground('video-bg-middle', middleColOffsetLeft, null);
        updateBackground('video-bg-right', -rightColOffsetLeft, null);
    };
    
    updateLeftMargin();
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateLeftMargin);
````

Comment: A proper [mre] that illustrates your issue belongs directly into your question; please do not _just_ link to external platforms.

Comment: I have already provided code examples without external links. There was a problem with code syntax highlighting and I couldn't post code blocks properla that's why I chose external links